# Force gradle to refer my lib instead of maven lib in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have one library jar which is also available in maven repository. When I add my jar in my lib folder, still I see gradle is referring to jar which is available in maven repository. But I want gradle to refer my lib as I added some more apis there.

Is there any way I can fix this issue? I tried making a new module out of this library and added as a dependent module as well. But still same issue.

Basically what I want is to make gradle to forcefully refer my library instead of maven library.